# What is bound states (in math)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

From picture below, seemly, bound states is the solutions of equation, is right ? But in wiki, bound states is a physical conception, and I can't understand it.

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same as the physical conception.  They are solutions where $|\psi|$ drops to zero as you leave the local minimum f the potential $V$, so the particle has little chance of being far away.  It is said to be bound to that minimum.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it. Could you tell me what is ground state ?

Comment: The ground state will be the lowest energy state near each local minimum.